# Python3 doesn't recognise my folder path even though it matches what the terminal shows

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 within a google vm. This is my first time working with python so apologies if this is really basic. When I run my code below I get an error message that my folder path wasn't found even though from what I understand it should be correct. Can someone confirm if there is something different I am meant to do when stating a folder path in python3 vs what I have done below?

### test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import imaplib
import base64
import os
import email

username = 'gmail_user'
password = 'app_password'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
rv, data = mail.login(username, password)

print(rv,data)
mail.select("blah")
type, data = mail.search(None, "All")   

print(data[0])
id_list = data[0].split() 

for num in id_list:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    raw_email = data[0][1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for part in email_message.walk():                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            continue                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            continue                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        fileName = part.get_filename()                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        if bool(fileName):                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            filePath = os.path.join('~/workshop/email-downloader/', fileName)                                                                                                                                                                            
            if not os.path.isfile(filePath):                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                fp.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            subject = str(email_message).split("Subject: ", 1)[1].split("\nTo:", 1)[0]                                                                                                                                                                   
            print('Downloaded "{file}" from email titled "{subject}" with UID.'.format(file=fileName, subject=subject))
```

### Error Message

> ```
> user@server:~/workshop/email-downloader$ python3 test.py
> OK [b'gmail_user authenticated (Success)']
> b'1'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
>     fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/workshop/email-downloader/dasd.txt'
> ```

Comment: Have you tried it without the `~`? Try replacing it with `./`

Comment: Use the absolute path instead.

Comment: @mapf I can confirm that I've tried some variations on the actual folder and that one provides the same error. However rethinking about that did help to give me the answer! it's treating it as within the folder so it's looking for my path from where the script is called from, so I have to define within that space!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where my script is being called from ~/workshop/email-downloader/

old path that doesn't work
filePath = os.path.join('~/workshop/email-downloader/', fileName)

new path that works
filePath = os.path.join('test/', fileName)